# why does Intellij change the ownership of files to root?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea, kde-plasma, ubuntu-15.04

Intellij keeps changing the ownership of workspace.xml of my SBT Scala project to root and does not let me save the project anymore.

How do I make Intellij store all files as me again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to start Intellij with a link on the quickstart menu in KDE. This seems to give Intellij the power to write as root. Start idea.sh directly from install folder with dolphin or bash.